# sed remove a special control character from many files

Tags: sed

Can someone please give me the exact syntax for removing ^@ from thousands of html files in nested directories using sed? The ^@ is a control character inserted by a windows program that generated these files. I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

I tried this (but it did not work) using a file since I could not enter the control-character at the command prompt:
find ./ *.html -type f -exec sed -i 's/^@//g' {} ;

Comment: Do you have really the token `^@` in your file ? Usually, it appears in many editor for not printable null character (aka 0x00h, NUL ASCII, \0).

Comment: About your sed command, if you have really the token `^@`, put a backslash \  just before `^` char. In regexp, `^` says "start with"

Comment: The ^@ was entered in vi as control-v control-@, not as text ^@.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POSIX sed doesn't handle NUL in input but GNU sed can with hex escape:

```
find . -name '*.html' -type f -exec sed -i 's/\x0//g' '{}' +
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I just tried it and it worked!